# Plant's output amounted to 10 000 tonnes, which is (was) 20% higher y/y.

Tags: tense-agreement

Suppose we have a news article describing a plant's performance in H1 2014, the period of time already finished by the moment the article goes into print. And we have to say that the plant's output of fertilizer totaled 10 000 tonnes over this period, marking a 20% y/y increase.

Would both the following formulations be OK grammatically:

> The plant's fertilizer output in H1 2014 amounted to 10 000 tonnes, which **is** 20% higher in year-on-year terms.
>
> The plant's fertilizer output in H1 2014 amounted to 10 000 tonnes, which **was** 20% higher in year-on-year terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction was that we should use simple past, **was**, but acording to [Collins COBUILD English Usage © HarperCollins Publishers 1992, 2004, 2011, 2012](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/which), usage #3, we can say:

> We heard about the awful conditions which exist in some prisons

So the present can be correctly used as well.